# Python 2.7 assertion error (noob needs help)

Tags: python, assertions

I'm fairly new to programming. I'm trying to write two class methods that will take a string, '{{name}} is in {{course}}' , and replace {{name}} and {{course}} with their respective Key values in a dictionary. So:

```
t = Template()
vars = {
    'name': 'Jane',
    'course': 'CS 1410'
    }

out = t.process('{{name}} is in {{course}}', vars)
print 'out is: [' + out + ']'
```

Would print:

```
Jane is in CS 1410
```

My code goes as:

```
class Template:

    def processVariable(self, template, data):

        print template
        assert(template.startswith('{{'))

        start = template.find("{{")
        end = template.find("}}")
        out = template[start+2:end]

        assert(out != None)
        assert(out in data)

        return data[out]

    def process(self, template, data):

        output = ""
        check = True

        while check == True:
            start = template.find("{{")
            end = template.find("}}")
            output += template[:start]
            output += self.processVariable(template[start:end+2], data)
            template = template.replace(template[:end+2], "")
            for  i in template:
                if i == "}}":
                    check = True 

        output += template

        return output

t = Template()
vars = {
    'name': 'Jane',
    'course': 'CS 1410'
    }

out = t.process('{{name}} is in {{course}}', vars)
print 'out is: [' + out + ']'
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
{{name}}
{{course}}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:some/filepath/name.py", line 46, in <module>
    out = t.process('{{name}} is in {{course}}', vars)
  File "C:some/filepath/name.py", line 28, in process
    output += self.processVariable(template[start:end+2], data)
  File "C:some/filepath/name.py", line 8, in processVariable
    assert(template.startswith('{{'))
AssertionError
```

I just don't understand why im getting that assertion error if template is '{{course}}'
Edit:
The purpose making the code this way, was to bring in any dictionary and string, so that I can create a simple social network. Otherwise much simpler methods would be proficient.

Comment: You know you can already do that in Python? `name = 'Pat'; print '%(name)s' % locals()`

Comment: @Paco or just `"{name} is in {course}".format(vars)`

Comment: Actually it is `'{name} is in {course}'.format(**vars)` (don't forget the `**`)

Comment: @Paco Yes... but i'll be using this class in an Web program that will be a simple social network. So the code wont know what the string even is, let alone the variables. Sorry, I'll edit so that the purpose of my code is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't actually getting the assertion error when `template` was `{{course}}`, which you can see for yourself if you change the `process` method to include some simple print statements, e.g.:

```
def process(self, template, data):
        # ...
        output += template[:start]
        print "Processing, template is currently:"
        print template
        output += self.processVariable(template[start:end+2], data)
        # ...

    return output
```

The actual problem was that `check` never became false. You can replace your if test with something like this, and then your function runs fine:

```
if not '}}' in template:
    check = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Marius  beat me to the answer to your question, but I just wanted to point out an easier way to do (almost) the same thing.  Ofcourse, if you're just trying to learn than the hard way is usually better.

```
vars = {
    'name': 'Jane',
    'course': 'CS 1410'
    }

out = '{name} is in {course}'.format(**vars)
print out
```